# ¿Cuales son las diferencias entre IEnumerable, ICollection e IList y cuándo debería usarse cada uno?

Tags: c#, .net

¿Existe alguna diferencia entre las interfaces `IEnumerable`, `ICollection` o `IList`?

¿En qué momento se debería usar cada una de las interfaces en mis desarrollos?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**IEnumerable:**

Se localiza en el espacio de nombres **System.Collections**. Existen dos interfaces definidas: una genérica y otra no genérica. Se puede observar en su definición de interfaz:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

Que el método `GetEnumerator` devolverá la instancia de un objeto de una clase que implemente la interfaz `IEnumerator`, la cual implementa dos métodos, `MoveNext()` y `Reset()` . También tiene una propiedad llamada `Current` que devuelve el elemento actual en la lista. Como principal característica, los IEnumerable pueden ser recorridos con la instrucción `foreach`.

**ICollection**

Al igual que en la anterior, también tenemos dos definiciones, una genérica y otra no.

```
 public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
    {          
        int Count { get; }
        bool IsReadOnly { get; }
        void Add(T item);
        void Clear();
        bool Contains(T item);
        void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex);   
        bool Remove(T item);
    }
```

Lo primero en lo que nos debemos fijar es en que hereda de `IEnumerable`, por lo que nos permite usar los métodos anteriormente mencionados.
También pueden ser recorridos, pero a diferencia de la anterior, ésta sí puede ser alterada.

**IList**

Al igual que en las dos anteriores, la biblioteca contiene dos definiciones, una genérica y otra no genérica.

```
 public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
    {
        T this[int index] { get; set; }     
        int IndexOf(T item);
        void Insert(int index, T item);
        void RemoveAt(int index);
    }
```

Como se observa, al implementar las interfaces anteriores, se pueden utilizar sus mismos métodos y además los propios, que como podemos observar están relacionados con la posición.

Ahora... **¿Cuándo deberías usar cada uno?**

La respuesta es que depende de qué nivel de accesibilidad necesites para tu código:

- **IEnumerable**:
  **Solo será posible iterar** sobre los elementos de la colección, por lo que se debería usar cuando se necesite **acceso de solo lectura**.
- **ICollection**: Permite **iterar sobre los elementos y acceder a ellos**, por lo que deberá usarse cuando se quiera **acceder, alterar o conocer el tamaño** de la colección.
- **IList**: Permite todo lo que las anteriores y además **indexación**, esto significa que la posición en la que se almacenan los datos es importante. Por lo que deberá usarse cuando se quiera tener una **colección ordenada** o acceder a **posiciones específicas**.

Comment: En la documentación de .NET hay un artículo interesante relacionado. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/selecting-a-collection-class

Answer (score 4):

Excelente la explicación de @Fran y me gustaría agregar algo mas.

Al seleccionar que tipo de lista utilizar, ademas de la interface debes seleccionar que Colección utilizar. Una colección puede implementar una o varias de las interfaces que mencionas por lo que la implementan de colección puede tener una o mas "habilidades" que @Fran menciona.

Muy importante es saber si quieres almacenar en la colección objetos del mismo tipo o de diferente tipo, o sea, guardar (y que solo permita) en la colección objetos de la clase Persona o bien guardar en a colección objetos string, int, Persona, Perro, etc.

En este link https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-collection puedes ver un gráfico de clases donde ves como se relacionan las interfaces y las clases que la implementan. En este caso las complementaciones permiten mezclar tipos de datos.
En este otro link https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-generic-collections menciona cuales son las colecciones donde permiten almacenar únicamente elementos del mismo tipo.

Podes ver que ICollection extiende a las otras dos interfaces y todas las implementaciones implementan esta interfaz por lo que al mismo tiempo implementan las 3.
Lo importante es que en la firma de los métodos siempre utilices alguna de las interfaces para no acoplar el método a una implementación en particular.