# Cuando implementar IEnumerable/IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, interface

Estoy aprendiendo c# de forma autodidacta. En el tema que da titulo el que enseñaba pone el siguiente ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace IEnumerable_IEnumerator_II
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Contenedor datos = new Contenedor();

            foreach (int el in datos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(el);
            }
        }
    }

    class Contenedor : IEnumerable
    {
        private int[] valores = new int[10];

        public Contenedor()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                valores[i] = i * i;
            }
        }
        
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (new ContenedorEnum(valores));
        }
    }

    class ContenedorEnum : IEnumerator
    {
        public int[] arreglo;
        private int posicion = -1; 

        public ContenedorEnum(int[] valores)
        {
            arreglo = valores;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            posicion++;
            if (posicion < arreglo.Length)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            posicion = -1;
        }

        public object Current
        {
            get { return arreglo[posicion]; }
        }
    }
}
```

si bien entiendo, o al menos creo entender que los metodos que implementan estas interfaces son las tripas del foreach, y tambien entiendo que se trate de un ejemplo para ilustrar dichas interfaces el caso es que se puede hacer lo mismo de la siguiente manera:

```
using System;

namespace IEnumerable_IEnumerator_II
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Contenedor datos = new Contenedor();

            foreach (int el in datos.Retorno()) //foreach invoca a GetEnumerator
            {
                Console.WriteLine(el);
            }
        }
    }

    class Contenedor
    {
        private int[] valores = new int[10];

        public Contenedor()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                valores[i] = i * i;
            }
        }
        public int[] Retorno()
        {
            return valores;
        }
    }
}
```

lo que yo quiero saber es en que caso deberia usar estas interfaces.
no lo voy a poner tambien aqui, pero hice algo parecido retornando un arreglo de objetos y funciona sin implementar nada.
busque en otros tutoriales y usan ejemplos similares donde no habria razon para usar las interfaces.
estoy seguro que los ingenieros en microsoft deben haberlas puesto por una razon mas que valedera y me gustaria saber cual.

P.D: tambien he leido aqui: [¿Cuales son las diferencias entre IEnumerable, ICollection e IList y cuándo debería usarse cada uno?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/264485/cuales-son-las-diferencias-entre-ienumerable-icollection-e-ilist-y-cu%c3%a1ndo-debe)  pero no me queda claro y tal vez sea porque no llegue todavia a las colecciones, pero si asi fuese, porque no usan un ejemplo con colecciones en vez de un simple array?

Comment: El final de la respuesta a la que enlazas es también la respuesta a esta pregunta. `IEnumerable`, sólo lectura; `ICollection`, por si necesitas alterar la colección o conocer su tamaño; `IList`, todas las anteriores más indexación. Está bastante claro. No te olvides que la interfaz es un **contrato** donde la clase que la implementa PROMETE declarar en su definición los métodos con el **mismo tipo de retorno, el mismo nombre y los mismos parámetros**, que los definidos en la interfaz

Comment: Esta respuesta puede servirte https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/432700/55132

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [IEnumerable vs IQueryable vs List](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/432645/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable-vs-list)

Comment: @Arriel ya lei eso y no lo entiendo. Sera que todavia me falta mucho por estudiar. Igual crei que algun tipo de coleccion necesitaba implementar las interfaces para poder iterarlos con foreach y lo que buscaba era algo como con xxx vas a tener q implementar las interfaces porque sino foreach t da error. Por otro lado el ejemplo que puse, que es de donde lo estudie es como querer reinventar la rueda

Comment: Si quieres entender desde la base te recomiendo que investigues sobre el patron Iterator, especificamente en C#